# Unable to convert project to Azure 2.6 - VS 2012

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2012, azure-sdk-.net

**Issue:** Unable to open project with Azure tools v2.6 on my Visual Studio 2012.

I am trying to open an Azure SDK 2.7 project in my VS 2012.
I get a dialog saying :

[image]

But sadly VS 2012 only supports Azure SDK till 2.6 version only. So I can't upgrade the Azure tools to latest on my system.

Also the 2nd option is disabled. **Can you please help me figure it out how to get the second option enabled** so that I can convert the project to use Azure tools v2.6 and open it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I don't know how you can enable this radio button, but please try the following the manually change the target SDK version from 2.7 to 2.6. I tried it with one of my projects and it seemed to work fine.

- Open up your cloud project's `ccproj` file in a text editor.
- Find `2.7` in that file and replace it with `2.6`. There will be 2 places where I think it is mentioned.

When I opened the solution and viewed properties of the cloud project, it told me that my project is using 2.6 and I can upgrade to 2.7 (so I think it is working fine).

I think you would need to manually change the references for all the SDK 2.7 related files (diagnostics etc.). Since I don't have VS 2012 on my machine and have SDK 2.7 installed, I was not able to test this part out.

I used this thread from MSDN forums as a reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8701b03a-804f-4953-9ea0-01064aa4dc16/downgrade-from-18-tools-to-17?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview.

Comment: Many thanks @Gaurav. It worked like a charm. I also had to remove the old references and add the v2.6 references as recommended by you. Thanks again.